# ie 8 session sharing between tabs causing an issues

Tags: internet-explorer-8

We are having links to two applications on the intranet page. And IE8 is the standard browser we use for our organisation. It is impossible to login into both application in two tabs.
Here is what happens:-
       1. User clicks on link of first application, it opens a new tab, and logs in. Login is successful.
      2. User clicks on link of the second application, the new tab is opened, but it says "page not found."

But if I click "new session" in ie and open the second application there, it works perfectly.

After having a bit of googling I cam to know about the "Session sharing in IE8 between tabs".
     First of all, I wanted to know why this is happening?
Second, I was looking for a way, in which i could tell the ie to start a new session, when I click the link. Is it possible?
Or can I do something on the server side?

Comment: are both applications made with the same technology (e.g. WebForms) ?

Comment: both are the SAP netweaver portals...

Comment: Well maybe they share information with the same cookie. Do they live on the same server ?

Comment: I dont know.. the web addresses are different.. i tried to ping the servers, got different ip addresses...

Comment: check out this post for Java solution
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21225958/3213575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First of all, I wanted to know why this is happening?*

This is because of a change in the way IE8 works.  More information is available on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963983/how-to-avoid-session-sharing-provided-by-ie8-programatically-in-java-j2ee-applic).

*Second, I was looking for a way, in which I could tell IE to start a new session, when I click the link.*
There is one way that might work for you.  Right click on the link you are using to start IE and select properties.  You should see something like the text below next to 'Target'.

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Add "-nomerge" to the end of the text, so you have the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -nomerge
```